# Key replacements / Key functions

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to run a function(or a line of javascript) by pressing a single key? For example, pressing the key `X` runs the fuction `example();`

My code (Pressing the `X` key runs `$("body").trigger($.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 32}));`)

```
    window.addEventListener('keydown', keydown);
window.addEventListener('keyup', keyup);
var speed = 25;

function example(){
     $("body").trigger($.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 32}));
}
var addEvent = document.addEventListener ? function(target,type,action){
    if(target){
        target.addEventListener(type,action,false);
    }
} : function(target,type,action){
    if(target){
        target.attachEvent('on' + type,action,false);
    }
}

addEvent(document,'keydown',function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if(key===88){
        example();
    }
});
function keydown(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 68) { //key D
        split();
        setTimeout(split, speed);
    }
     if (event.keyCode == 90) { //key Z
        split();
        setTimeout(split, speed);
        setTimeout(split, speed*2);
    }
     if (event.keyCode == 69) { //key E
        split();
        setTimeout(split, speed);
        setTimeout(split, speed*2);
        setTimeout(split, speed*3);
     }

}



function split() {
    $("body").trigger($.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 32})); //key space
    $("body").trigger($.Event("keyup", { keyCode: 32})); //jquery is required for split to work
}
```

Comment: I forgot to remove the unnecessary codes that has nothing to do with the question, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=>{
    if(e.key=="x"){
    console.log("You have pressed X")
    //Here you can call some function you need
      function();
    }
});
```

Here I am using lamda expression.You can place whatever function you need inside this expression.